# Add Space in the XSLT V 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, translate

I have two selects statements in the XSLT file.  What I'm trying to accomplish is to add a space in the output of the select statement.

For example, the following code:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(CAudioFile/CRI/PrivateData/PrivateData/DictionaryEntry[Key='CD1']/Value, ',',';')" />
```

returns this output:

> 9702195481; 31201(CCC AGENT)

I want to add a space right before the opening parenthesis.  So the output would be:

> 9702195481; 31201 (CCC AGENT)

I tried to use the "translate" function but it only allows two inputs.

The second select statement:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/CAudioFile/Agent/GroupsList/int"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></xsl:for-each>
```

returns

> 53115(ABCDE City IIM)

I would like to add a space before the first parenthesis.  So the output is:

> 53115 (ABCDE City IIM)

Any suggestions?

Thank you

**EDIT:**

When I use the following code, it works 99% of the time and it gives me the output I want:

```
<xsl:variable name="cd1"    select="CAudioFile/CRI/PrivateData/PrivateData/DictionaryEntry[Key='CD1']/Value" />
<xsl:value-of select="translate(substring-before($cd1, '('), ',', ';')"/>
<xsl:text> (</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after($cd1, '(')"/> 
<xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
```

The output is:

> 9702195481; 31201 (CCC AGENT)

However, there're times that the code will return a slightly different output:

> 9286136438; 31172 (GCG Agent), 18887113613

I want this code to replace EVERY comma with semicolon, the output from this string looks like this:

> 9286136438; 31172 (GCG Agent); 18887113613

This way I can keep them under one column.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Re your edit: this would not happen if you had used the answer you have marked as accepted-  where the translation is done on the entire value, before splitting it up. See: http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKvE/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing your value in a variable so it will be easier to reuse:

```
<xsl:variable name="string"  
              select="translate(CAudioFile/CRI/PrivateData/PrivateData/DictionaryEntry[Key='CD1']/Value, ',',';')" />
```

You can use `concat()` and `substring()` functions:

```
concat( substring-before($string, '('), ' (', substring-after($string, '(') )
```

The `(` can be used as a delimiter for the substring functions if it appears not more than once. This works in XSLT 1.0 or +.

Comment: How would I add the value in the varible in the foreach loop?

Comment: You don't need a variable, since it's only `@name`: `<xsl:value-of select="concat( substring-before(@name, '('), ' (', substring-after(@name, '(') )"/>`

Answer (score 2):

You can't use translate to replace one character with two. Try it this way:

```
<xsl:variable name="value" select="CAudioFile/CRI/PrivateData/PrivateData/DictionaryEntry[Key='CD1']/Value" />

<xsl:value-of select="translate(substring-before($value, '('), ',', ';')"/>
<xsl:text> (</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after($value, '(')"/>
```

or, if you prefer:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(translate(substring-before($value, '('), ',', ';'), ' (', substring-after($value, '('))"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. I got the first one working, however, I'm still having issue with the second one. Where I have @name in the foreach.
[link](http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKvE)

Comment: I don't see that you have multiple names, so why do you need for-each? http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKvE/2   If you do expect multiple names, then http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKvE/3

Comment: Got it. But I'm having issues with the first one. I don't have any controls over XML files.  When we replace the first ',' with ';' it only does it once. However, there're cases where it adds another comma after the ending parenthesis. Is there anyway, to replace all the ',' in the string with ';' so no matter how many commas added I still insert all the data in this column as one column. Here's an [Example]http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKvE/6

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the problem. I suggest you edit your question and post the code there - including the expected result. Make sure you clarify also how the different values need to be separated in the result - since you have one "cd1" value and one or more "name" values in the same string.